# Unity Firebase Analytics is not working

Tags: unity, android, analytics, firebase

I have been working on a new project in Unity 2021.2.12, where we need to implement Google Analytics. I have done as follows:

1. Imported Firebase Analytics package
2. Added the services.json file to the project's directory
3. Added the fingerprints to the Firebase Dashboard

However I am not receiving any data from the users. Does anyone have a similar experience? Have I done any step or the order of steps wrong?

Comment: This is more of a technical support question. You should start by going through the Firebase documentation and ensure you've followed all of the steps. If you're sure you've done everything right, you may have found a bug, so you should contact Firebase support.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your message, you are right, I just thought maybe someone else faced the same issue before. I added my findings, the problem was the order of doing the steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I did the process in the wrong order, basically forgot to add the service JSON file after I added the fingerprints, and thus it was failing.

A good practice can be that you make an APK build and try it on your phone or emulator and watch the analytics real-time section to see if any new user gets registered; then, it is an indication that the application is working.

I hope this information helps someone else in my position.